# How to install Laravel app to free web hosting?

Tags: apache, laravel, web-hosting

I've been serving my Laravel app on my local machine (MAC OSX Maverick) via the php artisan serve command in the terminal.

How do I install it to my a free a hosting for testing? Technically, I only have a free web hosting account. This means I can't perform any command-line commands (SSH). Is there any simple way to install it? Can I just simply copy my Laravel app folder and put it on a web host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Can I just simply copy my Laravel app folder and put it on a web host?"*

Pretty much this is the answer. You can upload your entire Laravel application to your webserver, and it should work.

But I'll warn you now that without command-line access - your going to have issues in the future. Try and find an alternative host for your website that provides command line access

Comment: Thanks this was really the answer. But still needed to change some directory paths and a few read/write permissions on under /app/logs/session/. Thanks :) I'll try to put what I did as an answer.

Answer (score 7):

Easiest solution: Deploy it to OpenShift using a [Laravel QuickStart](https://hub.openshift.com/quickstarts/115-laravel-5-0). OpenShift is free, gives you SSH access, and basing your app off the Laravel QuickStart should handle the more complicated configuration bits.